# System.OutOfMemoryException using ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading, out-of-memory, threadpool

I'm experiencing an unexpected behaviour while running some very simple code.

First of all I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on a i7-4770 CPU, 32Gb memory (22,6 free)

My sample code:

```
        int length = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int j = i;
            //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc_CLR, j);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ThreadProc_CLR(j); });
        }

        public void ThreadProc_CLR(object parameter)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(parameter);

            byte[] data = new byte[1000000000];
            new Random().NextBytes(data);
            System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(data);

        }
```

What I do not understand is why if I run my code using

- Platform Target: Any CPU
- Prefer 32-bit checked

I get a System.OutOfMemoryException after allocating the byte[] buffer for the 3rd or 4th time

If I uncheck "Prefer 32-bit" everything works smoothly. I've googled around looking for any docs explaining possible limitations but I haven't found any.

Comment: 32-bit means you can't allocate more than 2GB of RAM. Your code tries to allocate 10GB of RAM.

Comment: You're creating SHA1 instances without [disposing of them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289076%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when you've finished. That's probably leaky.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is completly correct - each iteration takes 1 billion bytes = 1 GB.

Comment: Related: [How much memory a x86 excutable can use on a 64bit os?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14089468/87698)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are working on a 64-bit OS.

When you compile with "Any CPU" and the "Prefer 32-bit" setting is turned on. Then the process will execute as 32-bit process even if the OS is 64-bit.

32-bit processes can have a virtual address space of size 2GB (can be 4GB using the LARGEADDRESSAWARE setting). This is a lot less than what you need for your application to run. Your application seems to allocate about 10GB, and the cryptography API is also going to consume some memory.

When you uncheck the "Prefer 32-bit" setting, the process will run as a 64-bit process. This gives you a virtual address space of 8 TB.

Comment: So basically "prefer 32-bit" means "force 32-bit". Understood, thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

You're not disposing of your HashAlgorithm instances, so they're probably sitting around consuming memory.

```
//...
using(var ha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create())
{
    ha.ComputeHash(data);
}
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, it isn't the source of the problem the OP is facing.

Comment: @Heinzi: I beg to differ. If OP is running out of memory after a number of passes, then yes, there is enough memory available in a 32-bit process to do what they want. Freeing it up will, most likely, avoid the necessity of switching to 64bit. Simply switching to 64-bit without understanding why the code chums up memory seems short-sighted to me.

Comment: You might have overlooked that the OP uses threading: the 10 instances with 1GB each are started *in parallel*. Thus, the 32 bit address space is *never* enough (unless, *by coincidence*, the scheduler totally serializes those 10 threads, but this is very unlikely), even if those instances correctly dispose their memory.